# Case sensitivity in Excel Data Model

Tags: excel, xcdatamodel

Does anybody know how to avoid error "The relationship cannot be created because each column contains duplicate values. Select at least one column that contains only unique values" in Excel Data model - data model consider ***idXYZ*** identical to ***idxyz***

Especially *salesforce.com* uses case-sensitive IDs.

Comment: change your data model to make identifier unique regardless of case?

Comment: @ForwardEd unfortunately I cannot change identifier. I am aware of 15/18 long identifiers in SFDC (18-chars-long are fine, but I have to use 15-long). Also I cannot make any concat colums (such as "ID"&"Name")